# custom_target() to extract and build external source

Tags: ninja, meson-build

I have a Meson project that will have a few steps:

- Download and extract a tarball
- `cd` into it, `./configure` - this produces a certain file in the upstream archive dir
- Adjust a file in the archive dir
- More build steps

The problem I have is how to set up the input/output files and the dependencies. So far I have:

```py
src_archive = 'extracted-dir' # this is what comes out of the upstream archive

# wget and untar a tarball (produces the 'extracted-dir' dir in the build directory)
dl_tgt = custom_target('download',
  command : [files('scripts/download.sh')],
  output : src_archive
)

# cd to the directory, .configure
# when this is complete, a file 'extracted-dir/docs/Doxyfile' will exist

upstream_doxyfile = 'Doxyfile' # can't set a path on this file
conf_tgt = custom_target('configure_src',
    input : dl_tgt,
    command : [files('scripts/configure.sh'), '@INPUT@'],
    output : doxy_out
)

# Modify the upstream Doxyfile (copy it and append some settings to the copy)

mod_doxyfile = 'Doxyfile.mod'

mod_doxy_tgt = custom_target('configure_doxy',
    build_by_default : true,
    input : conf_tgt,
    command : [files('scripts/configure-doxy.sh'), '@INPUT@'],
    output : mod_doxyfile
)

# ... and so on to run more steps as needed (in reality, some of these steps might be combined)
```

The reason to have separate steps if to allow Meson to avoid, say, repeating the download if the file is already downloaded.

If you try to run this, it won't be able to find the `Doxyfile`s (as they are in sub-directories).

If you specify them with paths, that's an error:

```
ERROR:  Output 'extracted-dir/docs/Doxyfile' must not contain a path segment.
```

I could also do it by manually specifying the paths within the scripts, but then the meson build is basically just an over-complex shell script without any dependency management.

How to chain up dependencies of files within the build directory like this?

Answer (score 1):

It happens to be limitation in meson, it is reported as an [issue](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/2320) and still open. However, for your Doxyfile modification custom target, substitution should work:

```
mod_doxy_tgt = custom_target('configure_doxy',
    input : doxy_out,
    ...
    output : '@BASENAME@.mod'
)
```

However, to solve the problem in general, consider creating another *meson.build* file in some directory where you extract upstream archive and include it to the main one with:

```
subdir('extracted_docs_dir')
```

so that Doxyfile is landed on the same level as that *meson.build*. Thus you could use file names in `output :`  directly, and it could be also good for isolation of this specific task from main build rules.

Comment: `@BASENAME@` is not supported in the `output` parameter of a custom target: https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#custom_target